# Fetching HTML content from Angular2 page programmatically with HttpClient from ASP.NET Core web application

Tags: c#, html, angular, asp.net-core, httpclient

I am trying to fetch HTML content programmaticallly from an Angular 2 page in my ASP.NET Core web application. What I want to do is parse and investigate HTML source code from some external Url. I am trying to do it with HttpClinet, example one:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:22222/vstsintegration/deletewi", null);
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

or example two:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = new HttpMethod("GET");
request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:22222/vstsintegration/deletewi");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

or with WebRequest and WebResponse, example three:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(value.urls[0]);
request.ContentType = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
Stream dom = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dom, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

In any case I am getting only basic HTML of this page. There is no HTML which comes from angular components in response. Probably, components are not loaded yet during request, and request is asynchronous so response is truncated.

Please, anyone has some suggestion how to load HTML fully, how to force request to wait for full page, with all components, to load. Also, any other opinion how to solve this other way is welcome.

Thanks a lot,
Vedran

Comment: I don't think you're going to accomplish this with httpclient.  If you do it this way you'll just see the source of the index.html page.  When you look at a angular app, the browser is running javascript in the background to generate the html, which httpclient doesn't do.  This is going to be a tricky problem to solve.  If you have access the web server, you could use nodejs to generate the pages on the server, then you're approach might be viable.

Comment: Yes, now I see only basic html. I have access to the server. How would look like solution with NodeJS?

Comment: Also, is there any workaround by using Http.get from @angular/http module? I mean, I tried this way also and it didn't work, but maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It's a bit of work and there are multiple methods. Here is an a tutorial which may work for you. http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html. Good luck.

Comment: I understand, you suggest me to redesign the application from which I want to fetch HTML so that it supports Server Rendering ... I wanted to do that without any interference into development of external web application. I have one more requirement from my side now to external application, what is bad.

Comment: Wait, but this external application has enabled server rendering:
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>. Still looks like HTML is not fetched properly. Why that?

Comment: I think you will need to point to the path referenced in the asp-prerender-module tag. I'm not quite sure though as I've used the prerendering for performance, not for what you're try to do.

Comment: I just don't understand why it doesn't work now because sever-rendering is enabled in application I am trying to fetch?

Comment: The only suggestion I have for you, is to login to the page with a a browser, and right-click view source.  What you see there, is what the httclient call will see. good luck.

Comment: I agree, it should be, but it is not in my case unfortunately. Never mind, thanks for your comments!